# Stuck at url encoding for map

Tags: php, dictionary, urlencode

My situation is like this, url encoding for map inside localhost returns one value while in the server it is another value. As a result I am not getting the proper result and i am stuck..By the way i have to use norwegian addresses for the map and the results are getting weird..

```
***localhost***
    <?php
    echo"enter zip";
    $Address="Stakkevollvegen 48 9010 Tromsø";
    $address=urlencode("$Address");
    echo $address;
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$address."&sensor=false";
    $details=file_get_contents($url);
    $result = json_decode($details,true);
    $lat=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lng=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    echo "Latitude :" .$lat;
    echo '<br>';
     echo "Longitude :" .$lng;
    ?>
```

This gives me an output like

```
Stakkevollvegen+48+9010+**Troms%C3%B8**Latitude :69.6634757
Longitude :18.9659889
```

While when i check the result in my server the output is like

```
***main program*** inside server
    $address=$db_emp_data[0]['tAddress'];
                echo $address;
                $Address=urlencode("$address");
                echo "<br />";
                echo $Address;
```

encoded code is like

```
Stakkevollvegen+48+9010+**Troms%F8**
```

Why is it like this? When i had put this

```
`Stakkevollvegen+48+9010+**Troms%F8**`
```

into my localhost I am getting notices and the latitude and longitude are not converting

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index1.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index1.php on line 26
Latitude :
Longitude :
```

Comment: What charset is used in your database?

Comment: Solved it by my self using$address=$db_emp_data[0]['tAddress'];
      $ad=urlencode( utf8_decode($address) );